# How to access azure advisor rest api

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I am working on azure advisor rest API and while i an hitting the following rest url with my token I am Getting 404 Not Found.

[Azure Advisor Link](http://%20https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionid/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/operations?api-version=2017-03-31)

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: Do you mean my access token?

Comment: Not access token....you must have written some code to execute that REST API. I was looking for that. Or are you using a tool like Postman?

Comment: Yes i am using postman with my access token

Comment: What is the URL you're using? Is it the same as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: it is same url which i mentioned here only the subscription id is differ.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141521/discussion-between-koderzzzz-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: I tried `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{my-subscription-id}/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/operations?api-version=2017-03-31` and it worked fine with me. I see an issue with the link you mentioned in your question. It is something like `http://%20https://https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/subscriptionid/providers/Microsoft.Advisor/operations?api-version=2017-03-31` which is incorrect.

Comment: This is the link [link](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{my-subscription-‌​id}/providers/Micros‌​oft.Advisor/operatio‌​ns?api-version=2017-‌​03-31)

Comment: the issue is that i am getting 404 not found

Comment: I tried the URL without access token and did not get a 404 error. Let me try it with access token though.

Comment: Without access token you will get 401 unauthorized.

Comment: I'm also getting a 404 error :(. I believe the API is not ready for public consumption. I had exact same issue with Microsoft.Billing resource provider. Please see comment on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/. This comment was posted after I raised the issue with the team at Microsoft yesterday.